# Firebreath and UTF-16

Tags: c++, windows, utf-8, utf-16, firebreath

I'm working on an international plugin, and I've run into trouble with UTF-16 strings. I'm trying to store logs to %APPDATA% using FB::FactoryBase::GetLoggingMethods. Currently it's defined like this:

```
void getLoggingMethods(FB::Log::LogMethodList& outMethods) {
  try {
    boost::filesystem::path appDataPath = FB::System::getLocalAppDataPath("AppName");
    boost::filesystem::path logDirPath = appDataPath / "Logs";

    if(!exists(logDirPath)) {
        // create the directory
        boost::filesystem::create_directories(logDirPath);
    }

    if (exists(logDirPath) && is_directory(logDirPath)) {
        boost::filesystem::path logPath = logDirPath / "app_name.log";

    outMethods.push_back(std::make_pair(FB::Log::LogMethod_File, logPath.string()));
        }
    } catch(...) { /* safely fail here */ }
}
```

The problem occurs when the user has a UTF-16 character in their username. This throws an exception.

But, `outMethods.push_back` requires a `std::string` for input. Converting from `std::wstring` to `std::string` loses that UTF-16 character (which makes the path invalid.)

Any ideas?

EDIT: managed to get it working by giving boost::filesystem::path a LPCWSTR for its constructor.

```
boost::filesystem::path appDataPath = 
    FB::utf8_to_wstring(FB::System::getLocalAppDataPath("AppName")).c_str();

boost::filesystem::path logDirPath = appDataPath / "Logs";

if(!exists(logDirPath)) {
     // create the directory
     boost::filesystem::create_directories(logDirPath);
}

if (exists(logDirPath) && is_directory(logDirPath)) {
    boost::filesystem::path logPath = logDirPath / "app_name.log";

    outMethods.push_back(
         std::make_pair(
             FB::Log::LogMethod_File, FB::wstring_to_utf8(logPath.wstring())
         )
    );
 }
```

Comment: Can't you just convert the UTF-16 string to UTF-8 before calling push_back, and then back again as necessary?

Comment: No, because any UTF-16 characters are lost in the conversion. So when the logger tries to open the directory (which has a UTF-16 char in the actual path) it fails because the path is wrong.

Comment: A conversion from UTF-16 to UTF-8 and back shouldn't lose any characters.  If you use a simple implementation, even illegal characters will translate back and forth without loss.  Do you mean that you can't modify the logger code to use UTF-8 for the path?